# How to link css stored outside public folder in symfony to twig

Tags: css, symfony, hyperlink, public

I'm trying to link css stored in src folder to twig which is also stored in src. Usually you can link your stylesheets using:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Is there a way I could do the same thing but with a file that is stored in src/folder/css ?

Comment: Excepts symlinks to the public dir, I don't see. Usually the assets are only in the "public" directory or in the "assets" if you use webpack encore or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this using a Service and Finder Component. I used FileManagerService as global in twig.yaml to make this css download more convenient.

src/Data/Templates/Template/index.html.twig

```
{% block templateCss %}
    <style>
        {{ FileManager.getCss('Data/Templates/Template/assets/css/index.css') }}
    </style>
{% endblock %}
```

src/Service/FileManagerService.php

```
public function getCss($path)
    {
        $css = '';
        $filePath = substr($path, 0, strrpos( $path, '/'));
        $fileName = substr($path, strrpos( $path, '/') + 1);
        $finder = new Finder();
        $finder->name($fileName)->files()->in($this->container->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/'.$filePath);
        foreach ($finder as $file) {
            $css .= file_get_contents($file);
        }
        return $css;
    }
```